# Não acessa o método OnResponse() retrofit android

Tags: java, android, json, return, retrofit

Estou realizando uma chamada de um metodo post que me retorna um id gerado através do retrofit 2, porém, no retorno, nunca acessa o metodo onResponse, já tentei usar outros objetos e formatos,mas nenhum funcionou. Abaixo o retorno do serviço:

```
 {  "_index": "smartfleet",  
    "_type": "op",   
    "_id": "AV2t5lWN2YWJ5ZApqt97",
    "_version": 1,
    "result": "created",
    "_shards": {
    "total": 3,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
},
    "created": true
}
```

Interface Retrofit:

```
@POST("op")
Call<ResponseOperacao> enviaOperacao(@Body Operacao operacao);

public static final Retrofit retrofitGraficos = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://minha.url.aqui/v1/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
```

A classe Operação que passo no metódo post, está ok, os dados estão sendo gravados no banco, o problema é apenas em pegar o retorno via onResponse().

```
Metodo call:RetrofitService servico = RetrofitService.retrofitGraficos.create(RetrofitService.class);
    Call<ResponseOperacao> call = servico.enviaOperacao(operacao);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseOperacao>() {
         @Override
         public void onResponse(Call<ResponseOperacao> call, Response<ResponseOperacao> response) {
             int code = response.code();
             if(code == 200){
                 System.out.println(response.body().getId());
             }
             else{
                 System.out.println(response.message());
             }
         }

         @Override
         public void onFailure(Call<ResponseOperacao> call, Throwable t) {
             System.out.println(t.getMessage());
         }
     });`
```

O a minha classe modelo de retorno:`public class ResponseOperacao {

```
@SerializedName("_shards")
@Expose
private Shards shards;

@SerializedName("_index")
@Expose
private String index;
@SerializedName("_type")
@Expose
private String type;
@SerializedName("_id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("_version")
@Expose
private Integer version;
@SerializedName("result")
@Expose
private String result;

@SerializedName("created")
@Expose
private Boolean created;`
```

Essa classe modelo está com contrutor e os Getters e setters já implementados, não adicionarei o código completo pro post não ficar muito grande.

Comment: Esse JSON está meio estranho. É um objetou ou array?!

Comment: Um objeto, estou enviando as informações pra um banco não relacional (elastic) e ele me retorna isso.